# SWIG and CMake: make use of information provided by `target_include_directories()`

Tags: c++, cmake, include, swig, include-path

With CMake 2.8+ you can avoid setting include directories redundantly by using [target_include_directories()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html).

E.g. by writing

```
add_libary(mylib SHARED ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC ./include)
```

.. you just have to link against `mylib` to add the needed include folder to your target.

But how can I make use of this information when I have to use CMake modules which don't make use of this capability yet? (in my case SWIG)

When I configure a SWIG project I currently have to hard code a lot of information:

```
set(SWIG_MODULE_${PYTHON_MODULE_NAME}_EXTRA_DEPS
    "../long/relative/path/1/include/some/header1.h"
    "../long/relative/path/1/include/some/header2.h"
    "../long/relative/path/2/include/some/header1.h"
    "../long/relative/path/2/include/some/header2.h")
```

I also have to use the old fashioned `include_directories()` to make the `swig` generator know what it needs to know:

```
include_directories(
    "../long/relative/path/1/include
    "../long/relative/path/2/include)
```

Otherwise the `%include` statements inside `.i` files won't work any more.

Of course I could set variables containing the paths but then I would provide the information I wanted to get rid of..

Is there a way to either extract the directory information from a target or (better of course) make the SWIG CMake module correctly use it?

**My current solution:**

With some (very beautiful) CMake magic you can automate listing all header files from the interface part of a library and set the include directories:

```
function(swig_add_library_dependencies swig_module library_names)
    foreach(library_name ${library_names})
        get_property(LIBRARY_INCLUDES 
                     TARGET ${library_name}
                     PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
        foreach(INCLUDE_PATH ${LIBRARY_INCLUDES})
            include_directories(${INCLUDE_PATH})
            file(GLOB_RECURSE header_files "${INCLUDE_PATH}/*.h")
            list(APPEND SWIG_MODULE_${swig_module}_EXTRA_DEPS ${header_files})
            # export variable to parent scope
            set(SWIG_MODULE_${swig_module}_EXTRA_DEPS 
              ${SWIG_MODULE_${swig_module}_EXTRA_DEPS} PARENT_SCOPE)
        endforeach()
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```

to be used like this:

```
swig_add_library_dependencies(<swig_module_name> "library1;library2")
```

or discretely like this:

```
swig_add_library_dependencies(<swig_module_name> library1)
swig_add_library_dependencies(<swig_module_name> library2)
```

Disadvantages:

- uses `GLOB_RECURSE`
- only works if target_include_directories had been used correctly
- creates dependencies to *all* header files found in include directories

Comment: As noted in documentation about `target_include_directories`, when used with PUBLIC keyword it populates [INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html#prop_tgt:INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES) of the target. So, you may extract information by reading this property.

Comment: +1 because it helps with `include_directories` but I still need redundant information for `SWIG_MODULE_*_EXTRA_DEPS`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation for `get_property`:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/get_property.html?highlight=get_property

you would do something like this:

```
get_property(MY_INCLUDES TARGET my_target PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
```

to get the interface include directories from the target my_target and store them in the variable MY_INCLUDES

Comment: This would indeed solve the problem with `include_directories` - but you would still have to invent something for the `SWIG_MODULE_*_EXTRA_DEPS` part. But since I explicitly asked how to extract that information you answered my question of course. I will keep the question open while tinkering with `get_property` a bit..

Comment: @frans ah I see. Those EXTRA_DEPS, can they be acquired algorithmically? For example by using a compiler to run a dependency sweep over some source files?

Comment: currently I'm trying to write a CMake macro which iterates over the INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES - I'll add my results to my question.

Comment: I was just hoping someone did this before :)

Comment: @frans yes, I've spent a lot of time with CMAKE wishing the same thing. I'm gradually building my own collection of useful macros to make CMakeLists.txt files easy to follow and maintain...